# Real time array cpp

Tags: c++, arrays

For example we have sample code

```
 cout << (((n%c == 0) && (n/c>=1)))?"Yes":"No";
```

in other languages like python we can do it more easily (concept in cpp).
how to realize it in cpp?

```
 cout << ... ["No","Yes"] [(((n%c == 0) && (n/c>=1)))];
```

we can declare array of "No", "Yes".
but how to do it just in time of writing to output.?

Comment: Does the first line work in C++?  If yes, why are you trying to now make that line look like another language (Python)?

Comment: You claim the second version is easier? I can't say I agree.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes it works. simply just to make experiments.

Comment: @Daniel, well if it's experimental, we're all lucky you don't know Lisp.  Who knows what concoctions you would want to come up with if that were the case.

Comment: hmm dont get in mind why this question has so many downvotes.. if it is not possible, just write that it cant be done.

Comment: Repeat this satement a million of times, and you'll get the overhead of a million of dynamic array allocation, deallocation on the top of your code...

Comment: @Daniel, maybe the downvotes are for "not useful"

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what does this have to do with C++ arrays?

Comment: @Christophe what debugger/ide use to see that alloc/dealloc of memory?

Comment: @Christophe:  How is the first statement allocating memory?  Looks like this could be accomplished with two registers (n & c) and some pointers to text constants.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews he talks about array alloc, see first answer, there is allocated at every time, a new array.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was talking about the second option, not the first !

Comment: @Daniel:  Simplifying the expression does not guarantee that the compiler will emit optimized code.  Let the compiler figure out the optimizations so you can spend your time on other parts of the project.

Comment: @Christophe second option, first answer. you were talking about array allocation or no? `new string[2]{"EE", "BB"}[rand()%2]` something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
cout << vector < string > { "A", "B", "C" }[1];
```

Comment: yes. definitely i was searching for.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with compiler optimizations set to high:

```
char const * answer = "No";
if ((n % c == 0) && ((n / c) >= 1))
{
  answer = "Yes";
}
cout << answer;
```

I'm pretty sure that the compiler will optimize this the same as your one line (with optimizations set high).  I prefer this as, IMO, it is easier to read and single step through with a debugger.

Comment: ok, the talk here is not about optimizing the code. but creating a new realtime constant array where from we can get values.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, you can do this:

```
typedef std::string ARRAY[];

int main()
{
    std::cout << ARRAY{"Yes", "No"}[0];
}
```

Not sure about C++03 because of the lack of brace initialization.

Comment: ye, C++11 awesome. but i want a C++03 version, if it exists.